# MySQL query, 2 similar servers, 2 minute difference in execution times

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ubuntu, mysql, sql

I had a similar question on stack overflow, but it seems to be more server/mysql setup related than coding.

The queries below all execute instantly on our development server where as they can take upto 2 minutes 20 seconds.

The query execution time seems to be affected by home ambiguous the LIKE string's are. If they closely match a country that has few matches it will take less time, and if you use something like 'ge' for germany - it will take longer to execute. But this doesn't always work out like that, at times its quite erratic.

Sending data appears to be the culprit but why and what does that mean. Also memory on production looks to be quite low (free memory)?

*Production:*

Intel Quad Xeon E3-1220 3.1GHz
4GB DDR3
2x 1TB SATA in RAID1
Network speed 100Mb
Ubuntu

*Development*

Intel Core i3-2100, 2C/4T, 3.10GHz
500 GB SATA - No RAID
4GB DDR3

**UPDATE 2 :**
mysqltuner output:

[prod]

```
-------- General Statistics --------------------------------------------------
[--] Skipped version check for MySQLTuner script
[OK] Currently running supported MySQL version 5.1.61-0ubuntu0.10.04.1
[OK] Operating on 64-bit architecture

-------- Storage Engine Statistics -------------------------------------------
[--] Status: +Archive -BDB -Federated +InnoDB -ISAM -NDBCluster
[--] Data in MyISAM tables: 103M (Tables: 180)
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 491M (Tables: 19)
[!!] Total fragmented tables: 38

-------- Security Recommendations  -------------------------------------------
[OK] All database users have passwords assigned

-------- Performance Metrics -------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 77d 4h 6m 1s (53M q [7.968 qps], 14M conn, TX: 87B, RX: 12B)
[--] Reads / Writes: 98% / 2%
[--] Total buffers: 58.0M global + 2.7M per thread (151 max threads)
[OK] Maximum possible memory usage: 463.8M (11% of installed RAM)
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (12K/53M)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 22% (34/151)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 16.0M/10.6M
[OK] Key buffer hit rate: 98.7% (162M cached / 2M reads)
[OK] Query cache efficiency: 20.7% (7M cached / 36M selects)
[!!] Query cache prunes per day: 3934
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 1% (3K temp sorts / 230K sorts)
[!!] Joins performed without indexes: 71068
[OK] Temporary tables created on disk: 24% (3M on disk / 13M total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 99% (690 created / 14M connections)
[!!] Table cache hit rate: 0% (64 open / 85M opened)
[OK] Open file limit used: 12% (128/1K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 99% (16M immediate / 16M locks)
[!!] InnoDB data size / buffer pool: 491.9M/8.0M

-------- Recommendations -----------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:
    Run OPTIMIZE TABLE to defragment tables for better performance
    Enable the slow query log to troubleshoot bad queries
    Adjust your join queries to always utilize indexes
    Increase table_cache gradually to avoid file descriptor limits
Variables to adjust:
    query_cache_size (> 16M)
    join_buffer_size (> 128.0K, or always use indexes with joins)
    table_cache (> 64)
    innodb_buffer_pool_size (>= 491M)
```

[dev]

```
-------- General Statistics --------------------------------------------------
[--] Skipped version check for MySQLTuner script
[OK] Currently running supported MySQL version 5.1.62-0ubuntu0.11.10.1
[!!] Switch to 64-bit OS - MySQL cannot currently use all of your RAM

-------- Storage Engine Statistics -------------------------------------------
[--] Status: +Archive -BDB -Federated +InnoDB -ISAM -NDBCluster
[--] Data in MyISAM tables: 185M (Tables: 632)
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 967M (Tables: 38)
[!!] Total fragmented tables: 73

-------- Security Recommendations  -------------------------------------------
[OK] All database users have passwords assigned

-------- Performance Metrics -------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 1d 2h 26m 9s (5K q [0.058 qps], 1K conn, TX: 4M, RX: 1M)
[--] Reads / Writes: 99% / 1%
[--] Total buffers: 58.0M global + 2.7M per thread (151 max threads)
[OK] Maximum possible memory usage: 463.8M (11% of installed RAM)
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (0/5K)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 1% (2/151)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 16.0M/18.6M
[OK] Key buffer hit rate: 99.9% (60K cached / 36 reads)
[OK] Query cache efficiency: 44.5% (1K cached / 2K selects)
[OK] Query cache prunes per day: 0
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (0 temp sorts / 44 sorts)
[OK] Temporary tables created on disk: 24% (162 on disk / 666 total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 99% (2 created / 1K connections)
[!!] Table cache hit rate: 1% (64 open / 4K opened)
[OK] Open file limit used: 8% (88/1K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 100% (1K immediate / 1K locks)
[!!] InnoDB data size / buffer pool: 967.7M/8.0M

-------- Recommendations -----------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:
    Run OPTIMIZE TABLE to defragment tables for better performance
    Enable the slow query log to troubleshoot bad queries
    Increase table_cache gradually to avoid file descriptor limits
Variables to adjust:
    table_cache (> 64)
    innodb_buffer_pool_size (>= 967M)
```

**UPDATE 1**:

When testing the queries listed here there is usually no more than one other query taking place, and usually none.

Because production is actually handling apache requests that development gets very few of as it's only myself and 1 other who accesses it - could the 4GB of RAM be getting exhausted by using the single machine for both apache and mysql server?

*Production:*

```
sudo hdparm -tT /dev/sda
/dev/sda:
 Timing cached reads:   24872 MB in  2.00 seconds = 12450.72 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads:  368 MB in  3.00 seconds = 122.49 MB/sec

sudo hdparm -tT /dev/sdb
/dev/sdb:
 Timing cached reads:   24786 MB in  2.00 seconds = 12407.22 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads:  350 MB in  3.00 seconds = 116.53 MB/sec

Server version(mysql + ubuntu versions): 5.1.61-0ubuntu0.10.04.1
```

*Development:*

```
sudo hdparm -tT /dev/sda
/dev/sda:
 Timing cached reads:   10632 MB in  2.00 seconds = 5319.40 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads: 400 MB in  3.01 seconds = 132.85 MB/sec

Server version(mysql + ubuntu versions): 5.1.62-0ubuntu0.11.10.1
```

**ORIGINAL DATA :**

This query is NOT the query in question but is related so ill post it.

```
SELECT 
    f.form_question_has_answer_id 
FROM 
    form_question_has_answer f 
INNER JOIN 
    project_company_has_user p ON f.form_question_has_answer_user_id = p.project_company_has_user_user_id 
INNER JOIN 
    company c ON p.project_company_has_user_company_id = c.company_id 
INNER JOIN 
    project p2 ON p.project_company_has_user_project_id = p2.project_id 
INNER JOIN 
    user u ON p.project_company_has_user_user_id = u.user_id 
INNER JOIN 
    form f2 ON p.project_company_has_user_project_id = f2.form_project_id 
WHERE 
    (f2.form_template_name = 'custom' AND p.project_company_has_user_garbage_collection = 0 AND p.project_company_has_user_project_id = '29') AND (LCASE(c.company_country) LIKE '%ge%' OR LCASE(c.company_country) LIKE '%abcde%') AND f.form_question_has_answer_form_id = '174'
```

And the explain plan for the above query is, run on both dev and production produce the same plan.

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys                                                                                                                                | key                              | key_len | ref                                                | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | p2    | const  | PRIMARY                                                                                                                                      | PRIMARY                          | 4       | const                                              |    1 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | f     | ref    | form_question_has_answer_form_id,form_question_has_answer_user_id                                                                            | form_question_has_answer_form_id | 4       | const                                              |  796 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | u     | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                                                                      | PRIMARY                          | 4       | new_klarents.f.form_question_has_answer_user_id    |    1 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | p     | ref    | project_company_has_user_unique_key,project_company_has_user_user_id,project_company_has_user_company_id,project_company_has_user_project_id | project_company_has_user_user_id | 4       | new_klarents.f.form_question_has_answer_user_id    |    1 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | f2    | ref    | form_project_id                                                                                                                              | form_project_id                  | 4       | const                                              |   15 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | c     | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                                                                      | PRIMARY                          | 4       | new_klarents.p.project_company_has_user_company_id |    1 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------+------+-------------+
```

This query takes 2 minutes ~20 seconds to execute.

The query that is ACTUALLY being run on the server is this one:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS num_results 
FROM (SELECT 
        f.form_question_has_answer_id 
    FROM 
        form_question_has_answer f 
    INNER JOIN 
        project_company_has_user p ON f.form_question_has_answer_user_id = p.project_company_has_user_user_id 
    INNER JOIN 
        company c ON p.project_company_has_user_company_id = c.company_id 
    INNER JOIN 
        project p2 ON p.project_company_has_user_project_id = p2.project_id 
    INNER JOIN 
        user u ON p.project_company_has_user_user_id = u.user_id 
    INNER JOIN 
        form f2 ON p.project_company_has_user_project_id = f2.form_project_id 
    WHERE 
        (f2.form_template_name = 'custom' AND p.project_company_has_user_garbage_collection = 0 AND p.project_company_has_user_project_id = '29') AND (LCASE(c.company_country) LIKE '%ge%' OR LCASE(c.company_country) LIKE '%abcde%') AND f.form_question_has_answer_form_id = '174' 
    GROUP BY 
        f.form_question_has_answer_id;) dctrn_count_query;
```

With explain plans (again same on dev and production):

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------+------+------------------------------+
    | id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys                                                                                                                                                                            | key                              | key_len | ref                                                | rows | Extra                        |
    +----+-------------+-------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------+------+------------------------------+
    |  1 | PRIMARY     | NULL  | NULL   | NULL                                                                                                                                                                                     | NULL                             | NULL    | NULL                                               | NULL | Select tables optimized away |
    |  2 | DERIVED     | p2    | const  | PRIMARY                                                                                                                                                                                  | PRIMARY                          | 4       |                                                    |    1 | Using index                  |
    |  2 | DERIVED     | f     | ref    | form_question_has_answer_form_id,form_question_has_answer_user_id                                                                                                                        | form_question_has_answer_form_id | 4       |                                                    |  797 | Using where                  |
    |  2 | DERIVED     | p     | ref    | project_company_has_user_unique_key,project_company_has_user_user_id,project_company_has_user_company_id,project_company_has_user_project_id,project_company_has_user_garbage_collection | project_company_has_user_user_id | 4       | new_klarents.f.form_question_has_answer_user_id    |    1 | Using where                  |
    |  2 | DERIVED     | f2    | ref    | form_project_id                                                                                                                                                                          | form_project_id                  | 4       |                                                    |   15 | Using where                  |
    |  2 | DERIVED     | c     | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                                                                                                                  | PRIMARY                          | 4       | new_klarents.p.project_company_has_user_company_id |    1 | Using where                  |
    |  2 | DERIVED     | u     | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                                                                                                                  | PRIMARY                          | 4       | new_klarents.p.project_company_has_user_user_id    |    1 | Using where; Using index     |
    +----+-------------+-------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------+------+------------------------------+
```

On the production server the information I have is as follows.

Upon execution:

```
+-------------+
| num_results |
+-------------+
|           3 |
+-------------+
1 row in set (2 min 14.28 sec)
```

Show profile:

```
+--------------------------------+------------+
| Status                         | Duration   |
+--------------------------------+------------+
| starting                       |   0.000016 |
| checking query cache for query |   0.000057 |
| Opening tables                 |   0.004388 |
| System lock                    |   0.000003 |
| Table lock                     |   0.000036 |
| init                           |   0.000030 |
| optimizing                     |   0.000016 |
| statistics                     |   0.000111 |
| preparing                      |   0.000022 |
| executing                      |   0.000004 |
| Sorting result                 |   0.000002 |
| Sending data                   | 136.213836 |
| end                            |   0.000007 |
| query end                      |   0.000002 |
| freeing items                  |   0.004273 |
| storing result in query cache  |   0.000010 |
| logging slow query             |   0.000001 |
| logging slow query             |   0.000002 |
| cleaning up                    |   0.000002 |
+--------------------------------+------------+
```

On development the results are as follows.

```sql
+-------------+
| num_results |
+-------------+
|           3 |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.08 sec)
```

Again the profile for this query:

```sql
+--------------------------------+----------+
| Status                         | Duration |
+--------------------------------+----------+
| starting                       | 0.000022 |
| checking query cache for query | 0.000148 |
| Opening tables                 | 0.000025 |
| System lock                    | 0.000008 |
| Table lock                     | 0.000101 |
| optimizing                     | 0.000035 |
| statistics                     | 0.001019 |
| preparing                      | 0.000047 |
| executing                      | 0.000008 |
| Sorting result                 | 0.000005 |
| Sending data                   | 0.086565 |
| init                           | 0.000015 |
| optimizing                     | 0.000006 |
| executing                      | 0.000020 |
| end                            | 0.000004 |
| query end                      | 0.000004 |
| freeing items                  | 0.000028 |
| storing result in query cache  | 0.000005 |
| removing tmp table             | 0.000008 |
| closing tables                 | 0.000008 |
| logging slow query             | 0.000002 |
| cleaning up                    | 0.000005 |
+--------------------------------+----------+
```

If i remove user and/or project innerjoins the query is reduced to 30s.

Last bit of information I have:

Mysqlserver and Apache are on the same box, there is only one box for production.

Production output from top: before & after.

```
top - 15:43:25 up 78 days, 12:11,  4 users,  load average: 1.42, 0.99, 0.78
Tasks: 162 total,   2 running, 160 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.1%us, 50.4%sy,  0.0%ni, 49.5%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   4037868k total,  3772580k used,   265288k free,   243704k buffers
Swap:  3905528k total,   265384k used,  3640144k free,  1207944k cached

top - 15:44:31 up 78 days, 12:13,  4 users,  load average: 1.94, 1.23, 0.87
Tasks: 160 total,   2 running, 157 sleeping,   0 stopped,   1 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.2%us, 50.6%sy,  0.0%ni, 49.3%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   4037868k total,  3834300k used,   203568k free,   243736k buffers
Swap:  3905528k total,   265384k used,  3640144k free,  1207804k cached
```

But this isn't a good representation of production's normal status so here is a grab of it from today outside of executing the queries.

```
top - 11:04:58 up 79 days,  7:33,  4 users,  load average: 0.39, 0.58, 0.76
Tasks: 156 total,   1 running, 155 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  3.3%us,  2.8%sy,  0.0%ni, 93.9%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   4037868k total,  3676136k used,   361732k free,   271480k buffers
Swap:  3905528k total,   268736k used,  3636792k free,  1063432k cached
```

Development: This one doesn't change during or after.

```
top - 15:47:07 up 110 days, 22:11,  7 users,  load average: 0.17, 0.07, 0.06
Tasks: 210 total,   2 running, 208 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.1%us,  0.2%sy,  0.0%ni, 99.7%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   4111972k total,  1821100k used,  2290872k free,   238860k buffers
Swap:  4183036k total,    66472k used,  4116564k free,   921072k cached
```

Comment: Is the configuration of your mysql the same on both machines?

Comment: The only difference in my.cnf was 'innodb_file_per_table = 1' on production, which I applied to the dev config but this didn't slow down the queries on dev.

Comment: I remember having read somewhere that 'Duration' is the time elapsed between the previous event and the current event. If that is true, this would mean that in your case sorting the data takes that long, not sending it. Still, that doesn't make a lot of sense to me.

Comment: 'innodb_file_per_table = 1' doesn't change anything on an existing database. You'd have to dump, drop the db, and reimport for it to take effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference might be from :

1. On the PROD server (Quad Xeon E3-1220 ) you have a RAID1 disk setup which might slow down the query as it's writing to 2 disks and reading from 2 disks http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID , which means slower performance on commits and greater performance on read operations (select ) . Depending on your application this might be a good or a bad thing ...
2. The swap partitions are different on both servers and it would seem that the RAM used /swap usage is different from PROD / DEV systems (even though they have the same amount of ram ). I would check for running processes with ps aux and compare the list as you will see that you have more processes running on prod .
3. Please have a look and see how many querry's concurrent connections you have on mysql / prod server .
4. Please have a look at disk speeds differences in prod and dev .
5. Do they have the same OS / mysql version and does innodb run as their engine on both environments ?

Comment: RAID1 writing does not perform slower than with a single disk.

Comment: I might be mistaken but as far as I know RAID1 provides write speed atmost as a single HDD setup (because it writes in both disk ) , please have a look here http://www.pcguide.com/ref/hdd/perf/raid/concepts/perfReadWrite-c.html  ,http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/250390-14-does-raid-increase-read-speed . Theoretically it can't be as fast as a single disk with the same specs . But if it is so , please let me know what would the reason be :)

Comment: mr12086 please test this if you don't find the bottleneck  somewhere else , based on the CPU types they seem to be "desktop" servers , which I would doubt that they have a good performance with the standard controller found on the mainboard .

Comment: I posted HDD read tests in OP just now along with mysql + ubuntu versions, but if there are any other tests i can run safely in production environment please let me know and i'll have a go.

Comment: When you run the query on PROD it would seem that there is a big difference in Sending data  136.213836 | that is more than two minutes as opposed to Sending data 0.086565 - in DEV, so it seems to be a network/ HDD issue ?

Comment: The guys who host our server have offered to do a chassis switch, but that means downtime so we are holding off atm. Is there anyway I can test for it being a network/HDD issue?  the read tests for the HDD seem to be ok from what I can tell, no?

Comment: Well they don't seem ok to me , as the difference is too big , please have a look here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/general-thread-states.html at Sending Data , and it shows a big difference (136 seconds - 2 minutes + ) . As you can see in the above link Sending data actually makes read operations , which seem to take too much in the PROD environment . If you have a lot of querrys running simultaneously on the prod server (besides this one ) , only then those 136 seconds might be explained.

Comment: Another method might be anything to make read operations on the disk (copy files ) , make a large simple select (on dev and PROD ) then show them the results .

Answer (score 1):

`| Sending data                   | 136.213836 |`

Looks like you might have interface saturation or network issues/throttling?

Other tests to run:

- Seat of the pants HD test ('second opinion on `hdparm -T`)

  - `dd if=/dev/zero of=1G bs=1M count=1024`
- Seat of the pants network test

  - `scp 1G user@anotherhost.com`
  - or: use something like `iftop`

As you conjectured in your post: 
Memory doesn't appear to be an issue - most of it is used for cache and there's no indication of heavy swapping.

Answer (score 1):

There has to be a difference somewhere. Are you sure you have exactly the same data on both servers or could it be that one table on the production server is significantly larger?

Maybe you are searching in the wrong direction. I would start by running [mysqltuner](http://mysqltuner.pl) on both systems. That script will give you suggestions as to how the setup can be tuned. If you have exactly the same setup on both systems, it should give you the same or similar suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

1. The data is different on both machines or at least there is more on one of them.
2. You key_buffer is 16M and innodb_buffer is 8M
3. The buffers are soooo small that your prod server, averaging 7 queries a second, is probably blowing the cache on ever single query.

I suspect that on your Dev server queries get to use the whole 8M innodb buffer in a single query while prod has to share 7 queries across the same 8M. Depending on the data needs of those queries your performance oscillates between bad and horrible.

Simplest solution is to set this in your my.cnf and see if things get better.

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1G
```

Also bump the key_buffer as well since you're got 100M of myisam tables.

```
key_buffer = 128M
```

You might need to play with these numbers since Apache is on the same server, but I'd do at least 500M for the innodb buffer.

Comment: Not sure if its related, but I'm having trouble getting my.cnf changes recognised..  I add the change to /etc/mysql/my.cnf do a sudo service mysql restart.. and no change happens to show variables in mysql cl. The same my.cnf file (copied just now) works fine and updates the vars on dev...

Comment: Make sure you're adding the changes within the [mysqld] portion of your my.cnf and not just at the bottom of the file.

Comment: Ye, got all that checked opened a question here : http://serverfault.com/questions/394651/mysql-my-cnf-ignored  but still unsure of what is happening :S

Answer (score 0):

Ok, shortly after this issue our server went offline, and we are told the raid was corrupt - new hdd's and reinstall of our web application - everything is running normally again, with similar to the performance of the dev system.