# my.cnf file does not reflect changes on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, my.cnf

Hello I am running an application install which requires `thread_stack = 256k`
in my.cnf file. The location of the file is `etc/mysql/my.cnf` and I updated the value and restarted the mysql server,but the value does not get updated even after the restart.

**MySQL version is 5.5.35-0ubuntu0.12.04.2**

On exeecuting the below query I get the size as `196608`

```
    SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%stack%'
```

I referred [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/394651/mysql-my-cnf-ignored) thread and tried the start stop way but did not work.How can I make the file to be reloaded on restart?

**EDIT**

```
   service mysql start --thread_stack=256K
```

This command line option also did not work with error start: invalid option: --thread_stack=256K

I just checked that after running service mysql stop I am able to connect to mysql and if I do a pgrep,I can see two pid's.
Is there another mysql instance running which is causing this issue? DO I need to kill the processes?

```
     root@ip-10-155-22-27:/# service mysql status
     mysql stop/waiting
     root@ip-10-155-22-27:/# pgrep mysql
     12813
     13103
     root@ip-10-155-22-27:/# mysql -u root
     Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
     Your MySQL connection id is 90524
     Server version: 5.5.35-0ubuntu0.12.04.2 (Ubuntu)
     Copyright (c) 2000, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

     Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

     mysql>
```

Comment: What if you write it out, e.g. put a line 'thread_stack=262144' in my.cnf and restart?

Comment: tried it and restarted number of times, but it still does not reflect.

Comment: Actually because it did not work with writing I went the command route

Answer (score 0):

Well I found a solution. The issue was **multiple processes**(threads) running for mysql. The output of `pgrep` in the question led me to use `kill -15 -1`.

This kills all the active processes for applications. Then I had to restart mysql and apache and I had the value updated.

The comments in the linked question I added by **@kashani**  helped a lot.

I hope this helps someone.